# Read float values from file, c#

Tags: c#

I have a binary file that is created using Android. Using a c# application to read that file. I want to read the floating point values written in that file. Rest of the other values int, char etc are succesfully read from it.

I am used ReadInt64() and it is not returning correct value...

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: show your code? and tell us what problem are you facing?

Comment: How does the file look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use ReadSingle(). It will read the floating point values from binary file.